# C scr_restore function not working

Tags: c, curses

Hello everyone I am writing this program that "can" be capable of restoring the dump file created by scr_dump();. The dumping part is working, but not the restoring part.. The goal of this is to copy whatever is on the standard screen and copy it into a file, and by calling that file back again it should draw whatever was there initially.

```
          int firstLoop = 0;

            initscr();
    while (exitCounter != 1)
    {

               if (firstLoop == 0)
               {
                   printw("Testing 123");
                   scr_dump("test");
                   clear();
                   firstLoop = 1;
                    exitCounter = 1;
               }
        }


                   scr_restore("test");
                   doupdate();
                   refresh();


            getch();

            endwin();
        }
```

Comment: When is the restore supposed to happen? Every time this function is called, `firstLoop` is initialized to 0. It will never be anything else when the `if` statement is reached.

Comment: Take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Profit.

Comment: okay, just fixed it still doesn't work

Comment: After trying a few things out on my own, I'm as confused as you are. All the documentation I've found says this should work. It seems a little odd to be running a screen dump and restore in the same function, so I'll try a few more things and may post a real answer if I have one.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a call to `refresh()` after your `printw()` call, otherwise you're dumping a blank screen.

With this code:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main(void) {
    initscr();
    noecho();

    printw("Testing 123");
    refresh();

    scr_dump("test");
    clear();

    getch();

    scr_restore("test");
    doupdate();
    refresh();

    getch();

    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

you should see a blank screen, then after hitting a key, see your `"Testing 123"` message. Both `scr_dump()` and `scr_restore()` can fail, so obviously you should be checking the return values.